# Como mudo ordem da inserção do banco de dados MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, phpmyadmin

Quero que ao inserir algo no meu MySQL (PhpMyAdmin) ele insira e cima da última postagem. Exemplo:

Ontem inseri `Nome: Pedro | Idade: 20 Anos`

e ele ficou no topo por ser o primeiro a ser inserido no banco de dados

Hoje desejo inserir> `Nome: João | Idade: 21 Anos`

Porém ele tem que ficar em cima do Pedro, a ordem da visualização do banco de dados ele precisa ficar no topo.

É possível fazer isso?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Não existe isto que você está pensando. O banco de dados é um mecanismo de armazenagem e consulta de dados. Você não estabelece como será armazenado, isso é problema dele fazer, os dados só estão lá, não importa como. Você insere o que precisa e acabou, não tem a menor relevância como foi inserido.

Quando você for consultar é que precisa dizer como quer que os resultados voltem. Portando o segredo está no `SELECT`, ali você vai dirá a forma das informações serem trazidas para você.

A pergunta não dá detalhes para poder ajudar melhor, mas provavelmente seria algo assim:

```
SELECT * FROM tabela ORDER BY id DESC;
```

Veja [funcionando no **SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/555882/1). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/tree/master/SQL/Select).

Se tiver uma coluna chamada `id` que é auto incrementada. Normalmente é assim que faz. Se não tiver uma coluna com um valor que seja garantidamente em ordem crescente não tem como fazer o que quer no MySQL, de qualquer forma isso provavelmente já é um erro. Criar um índice para lidar melhor com esta ordem pode ser fundamental para manter boa performance em bases com muitas linhas.

Comment: dessa maneira aí sempre q eu for adicionar uma nova pessoa preciso usar esse comando aí, tem como eu deixar permanentemente em DESC?

Comment: @Kleyner na verdade isso não tem nada a ver com o `inserir` usuário e sim na hora da consulta. Você irá inserir os dados normalmente, sem se preocupar com ordem alguma, na hora de exibir os dados `select`, que você irá usar o `DESC`, assim, os resultados serão exibidos de forma descendente. Concluo reafirmando: Não se preocupe na ordem que os registros são inseridos, o importante é na hora de puxar esses dados do banco.